# Laptop Microphone doesn't work anymore

Tags: gnome, 16.10, microphone

My laptop microphone has been working since I had my laptop (about 1.5 years ago) and it has only ever run ubuntu gnome. Since Oct 2016 I have been using UbuntuGnome 16.10. This month the microphone stopped working. It doesn't work in sykpe and I can't use sound recorder to make recordings.

What could have happened? Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Install pavucontrol. Open it, you can change the settings from there and check what has gone wrong. Include a screenshot of the input devices tab and configuration tab in the question

Comment: Here is my screebshot: http://imgur.com/a/txc0B

Answer (score 0):

Investigate. It could be related to physical damage, loose connection, corrosion, driver removal or substitution for a wrong, unsupportive or damaged one etc etc. It is hard to say. I think the most likely is that some hardware problem occured. Try to live boot different OS or build, work with drivers, try different devices... As with everything, try to investigate in that manner - beginning with easiest, accessible options (yet with some potential cause), ending with the hardest and the most work-requiring options.

Comment: Sorry it is actually 10 months old. Nothing has happened to it, the only thing that gets updated is software. The hardware hasn't been changed and no damage has been done to it. It is also a laptop made for inux

Comment: Then try the live boot maybe.